# Facebook PHP SDK Graph API posting links/feed not showing "via AppName"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook Graph API to post a link to a Page. The post comes up successfully but the link I see on some posts underneath where it says `via AppName` doesn't appear. Is there something I have to do to explicitly enable this?

```
$message = sprintf("Message test");

$link = array(  'link' => JURI::base() . 'share/' . $id,
                                        'message' => $message,
                                        'access_token' => $page->access_token
                                        );

$res = $facebook->api('/'.$page->id.'/links', 'POST', $link);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Posts made through applications on a page don't show **via AppName** in the posts. 
It is some feature made for the posts on Pages.
 Although if you query for the either `feed` or `post_id` end-points you can know if that post was made by some application or not, by the presence of key `application` in the returned result, which tell `name` , `namespace` and `id` of application .

Comment: The AppName comes up on the facebook mobile app, just not on the website, just seen that now. Do you think it's just a change they have made?

Comment: Might be, because I came across a similar post as yours here in StackOverflow and there it was mentioned the same thing. I tried to find that for your reference but couldn't find it out. Sorry for that.